# Inserting a space/view/image between UITabbar Items

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbar

Porting an app to the ipad and in Landscape the tabbar looks a bit sparse so had the idea of separating the tabs (6 of them) and inserting an image between them.

I currently use `TabBarKit` and it does everything and more the `UITabbar` does, but this is something I am kind of stuck on. Having trouble finding any way to insert empty space, either an image or `UIView` (the background is already an image)?

What I've done so far is to add several extra tabbar items programmatically and set the image to nil and removing user interaction.
(I found this solution on another stackoverflow thread, but it's not a perfect solution).

I know `UIToolbar` has a flexible space item but when I tried to use this as a `tab bar item` it caused some issues.

So if anyone has any ideas on how to insert a view, empty space etc into the tab bar it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Started a bounty because I'm curious to see if this can be done or not.
The ipad landscape view has loads of room and I've been asked to put an image in the middle splitting the buttons.

If the app gets rejected then more the fool me. Any examples, samples, suggestions, advice greatly appreciated

Image example:
[image]

Comment: it's too much difficult to understand your problem please post an image of tabbar so one can easily replied.

Comment: Image uploaded, thanks for the idea mate

Comment: I don't know this is posible or not but you can arrange buttons look like tabbar and manage button event with images

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, are you saying replace buttons with images? Can you give a little more detail please

Comment: see if the design above you show is possible in TabBar then i don't know how but if you would like to make it same then you can take 6 button and 1 image. Set the image between this image. make images look like in tabbar both for selected and unselected and set according to coordination set the whole background image. and handle button pressed like tabbar controller. got it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd agree with the answer above that this is probably not a great idea, technically though, it is possible.

The trick to a custom tabbar is to hide the default tabbar and place your own custom view in that space.  Then you can fill that view with buttons, images, really whatever you want.  Here is how I handled this.

I set up my UITabbarController like this in the AppDelegate:

```
UITabBarController tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, 
                                             viewController2, 
                                             viewController3,
                                             nil];
//add the custom tabbarcontroller
CustomTabBar customTabBar = [[CustomTabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height - 60, self.window.frame.size.width, 62)];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:_customTabBar];

tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

The CustomTabBar is a subclass of UIView where I put my own custom buttons.  When a button in this class is clicked, I make a call that looks like this:

```
-(void)firstBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    ((UIButton*)sender).enabled = NO;
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would discourage you from messing with Apple's well thought out spacing for the tab bar. Don't do this - you're hacking a native control in a bad way and this will have consequences down the road. Also, you'll have to deal with different spacing and logic in landscape vs portrait mode. Don't complicate things unnecessarily, use it as designed or rethink whether a tab bar is the appropriate control.

Quoting from [Apple's guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52):

> On iPad, display the same tabs in each orientation to increase the
>   visual stability of your app. In portrait, the recommended seven tabs
>   fit well across the width of the screen. In landscape orientation, you
>   should center the same tabs along the width of the screen. This
>   guidance also applies to the usage of a tab bar within a split view
>   pane or a popover. For example, if you use a tab bar in a popover in
>   portrait, it works well to display the same tabs in the left pane of a
>   split view in landscape.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The app is being locked in Landscape mode for the iPad and the iPhone version is locked in portrait.
Just thought the image between them would look good and give an open feel to the app

Comment: Having extra images in there will confuse your apps users. Don't do it.

Comment: I gave you the bounty because I believe you are right but it's something I've been asked to do. Cheers for the info